# Repeater Button CommandArgument is Empty String

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, commandargument

Losing my mind with this one. My button gets a commandargument of empty string even though the commandargument gets set. I have verified it gets set to the correct ID in debug mode, but then when I go to access this commandargument later in the repeaters ItemCommand event the commandarguments are empty string. And I have no idea why. I end up getting a sq foreign key exception because it is inserting an ID of 0 from the empty string values. There is no other code regarding the repeaters buttons that would be resetting it.

Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterAddresses" ViewStateMode="Enabled" DataSourceID="sqlFacilityAddresses" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <Select:Address ID="AddressControl" runat="server"  />
        <asp:Button ID="btnMarkAsBilling" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" CommandName="Billing" Text="Mark as billing address" />
        <asp:button ID="btnMarkAsPhysical" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" CommandName="Physical" Text="Mark as physical address" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
    Protected Sub repeaterAddresses_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles repeaterAddresses.ItemCreated
        If Not IsNothing(DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)) Then
            If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
                Dim addressControl As Address = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("AddressControl"), Address)
                addressControl.AddressID = CInt(DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)("Address_ID").ToString())
                Dim btnBilling As Button = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("btnMarkAsBilling"), Button)
                btnBilling.CommandArgument = CInt(DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)("Address_ID").ToString())
                Dim btnPhysical As Button = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("btnMarkAsPhysical"), Button)
                btnPhysical.CommandArgument = CInt(DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)("Address_ID").ToString())
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
   Protected Sub repeaterAddress_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles repeaterAddresses.ItemCommand
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Trustaff_ESig2").ConnectionString)
        Dim button As Button = CType(e.CommandSource, Button)

        Select Case e.CommandName
            Case "Billing"
                Dim cmdBillingAddress As New SqlCommand("[SP_Facility_UpdateBillingAddress]", conn)
                With cmdBillingAddress
                    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Facility_ID", DbType.Int32)).Value = sqlFacilityAddresses.SelectParameters("Facility_ID").DefaultValue
                    .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@BillingAddress_ID", DbType.Int32)).Value = e.CommandArgument
                End With
                conn.Open()
                cmdBillingAddress.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
            Case "Physical"
                Dim cmdPhysicalAddress As New SqlCommand("[SP_Facility_UpdatePhysicalAddress]", conn)
                With cmdPhysicalAddress
                    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Facility_ID", DbType.Int32)).Value = sqlFacilityAddresses.SelectParameters("Facility_ID").DefaultValue
                    .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@PhysicalAddress_ID", DbType.Int32)).Value = e.CommandArgument
                End With
                conn.Open()
                cmdPhysicalAddress.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
        End Select
        PopulateBillingPhysicalAddresses(sqlFacilityAddresses.SelectParameters("Facility_ID").DefaultValue)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMarkAsBilling" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" 
    CommandName="Billing" Text="Mark as billing address" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Address_ID") %>'/>
```

Note the single quotes around the attribute value.  ASP.NET will not execute the server side data binding code if they are double quotes.  You'll need to remove the `CommandArgument` assignments from your code behind.

`Address_ID` will need to be a property on the object you are databinding to the repeater.

Comment: This worked but I don't understand why the code behind setting of the commandargument doesn't work. I have used it many times with gridviews that way and it has worked just fine.

Comment: Is your databinding code wrapped in a check for Page.IsPostBack?

Comment: Been messing around with this for a while and did not have a clue about the need of using single quote rather than the normal one.. Thanks a lot!