# Set OnClick for ASP:Button inside ASP:Repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following asp:Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptResults">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="FileFile Large pdf SearchResult">
            <a href='<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).Link %>' style="text-decoration:none">
                <%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).BackgroundHTML%>
                <p style="float:left;line-height:32px;margin:0px"><%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).Filename%></p>                                            
            </a>
            <p style="float:left;line-height:32px;margin:0px; margin-left:20px;">Path:  <%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).Link%></p> 
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteFile" Name="<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).Link%>" Text="Delete" Style="float:right;margin-top:8px;cursor:pointer;"/>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My problem is trying to set an OnCLick listener.

First I tried:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnDeleteFile_Click" ID="btnDeleteFile" Name="<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).Link%>" Text="Delete" Style="float:right;margin-top:8px;cursor:pointer;"/>
```

and:

```
Protected Sub btnDeleteFile_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Write("KDKDK")
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

But that caused `Invalid postback or callback argument.`

Which I suspect is because I cannot set an `OnCLick` listener inside a repeater?

I then tried:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteFile" Name="<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).Link%>" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Delete" Style="float:right;margin-top:8px;cursor:pointer;"/>
```

and

```
Protected Sub rpt_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) 
    If e.CommandName = "Save" Then
        'Save
    End If
End Sub
```

Which did not cause the postback error, but did not fire the event. I suspect this is because the listener had not been assigned to the button?

If I add a handles eg:

```
Protected Sub rpt_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles rpt.ItemCommand
```

Which gave the error:

```
Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.
```

But I cannot see how to assign a WithEvents variable, and I am not sure this will work inside a repeater.

I will not keep boring you with every last ting I have tried, but I have searched all I can but cannot find anything that shows me how to set this OnCLick event?

Comment: Try adding an OnItemCommand to your repeater and make your button a CommandButton. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

A few things; there is no button name property, and this could be causing issues if it's sending text directly up to the client.  For ItemCommand to work, give the button a command name, and (optionally) an arg if one exists:

```
<asp:Button .. CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="OPTIONAL" />
```

That should then trigger the ItemCommand event.  For the name parameter, you can pass `<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).Link%>` via the CommandArgument.  You can also use [Eval as in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796564/repeater-button-commandargument-is-empty-string).  I believe Eval supports dot notation too.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake:

```
Protected Sub rpt_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles rptResults.ItemCommand
```

and:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteFile" commandname="<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).Link%>" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Delete" Style="float:right;margin-top:8px;cursor:pointer;"/>
```